# Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed le-connection-abort-by-local when trying to connect to my headphones

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, laptop, headphones

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I am trying to connect my laptop to my galaxy buds 2 pro, but to no avail

I tried doing it on the terminal by typing

```
sudo bluetoothctl
devices
trust F0:94:D4:0F:97:C4 #my headphone's mac address
connect F0:94:D4:0F:97:C4
```

I also tried with the command pair instead of connect

I am then met with the error message

```
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationRejected
```

I have no idea what I can do to troubleshoot/fix, I installed Ubuntu just this week

I tried almost anything I could find online, I've been at this for hours

Any help would be appreciated